# making insertItemsAtIndexPath in UICollectionView not to animate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using UICollectionsView insertItemsAtIndexPath and it is very annoying such that when I am scrolling on the UICollectionView and then it calls insertItemsAtIndexPath it slides with the item. I want this inserting to be seamless and just append it to the top without user knowing that something has been appended on top. How can I do this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you will  have to subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and then in the `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath` just return nil. That way, it will directly place it to the final position and hence no animation should take place.

Comment: so it still does some animation after trying it out.. I can see it flash

Comment: has no effect in iOS 9